# Android phone doesn't start, screen black

Tags: screen, troubleshooting

So yesterday i picked my phone up from my pocket, the screen was on but just black, and it was blinking (guessing around 7 seconds of, 7 seconds black). After a few hours of doing this, it sounded like it turned on or off, but nothing had changed. It was still just blinking. I also tried holding the power button for at least 2 minutes but nothing. Next change happened at half past eleven where it again sounded like it had turned on/off. But this time when i hold the power button, it sounded like it turned on, and after that i could turn the screen on or off, but it was still just black. Next morning, when pressing the power button, it turned "on" i could switch the screen on/off, and after 5 minutes it shut itself down again. This happened again. When i turn it on, it doesn't display the right splash screen, rather just black like usual.

Upon plugging it into a computer with android studio installed, and running adb devices, it doesn't show up (haven't tested while it is in the mode where i can control the screen since i haven't got access to a computer that has as rn, will update once i tested it). Right now i am trying to discharge it completely and see what happens when i charge it and turn it on. After it being discharged, i can turn it on, it seems to boot up like normal, taking the normal amount of time, but without image. After that i can turn on and off the screen, it also turns itself off after awhile like normal. After about 15sec to 5 minutes it then shuts itself down completely again

Earlier that day, i had just browsed some twitter, and tested a react native app. One thing that i did do was clean it in the sink, but it is a IP68 phone, the rubber around the corners have started becoming a bit loose, but the actual phone seems to be encased in an inner hard plastic shell. It's a lower end device from china, a Nomu S10 Pro to be specific, which i've had since Aug 2018.

Could it be the screen that is dead?

### Update

i'm pretty certain the screen is dead, i plugged it into my PC, remembered the Microsoft Your Phone/Phone companion or whatever, and i could send messages, i could even view photos, so i took a screenshot, and it showed up. :(

Comment: you can take screenshots? that might be helpful for enabling usb-debugging, and finally you can get full control https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc

Comment: it should be possible to root with SP Flash Tool + Magisk (on locked bootloader) and make full backup with Migrate (if you care)